# Resume mirroring via wget

Tags: wget

I want to mirror all files for example [KDEs](http://alien.slackbook.org/ktown/current/4.12.1/x86_64/kde/) to local directory. I used

```
$ wget -m -P ./kde http://alien.slackbook.org/ktown/current/4.12.1/x86_64/kde/
```

But after a while it broke. To continue I added `-c` option and tried again. As :

```
$ wget -c -m -P ./kde http://alien.slackbook.org/ktown/current/4.12.1/x86_64/kde/
```

But got the following error (I get error in second time I tried if it downloaded `index.html` previously):

> Saving to: './kde/alien.slackbook.org/ktown/current/4.12.1/x86_64/kde/index.html'
>
> [ <=>                                   ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s
>
> Cannot write to './kde/alien.slackbook.org/ktown/current/4.12.1/x86_64/kde/index.html' (Success).
>   Converted 0 files in 0 seconds.

And downloading breaks again at this point. How should I continue a `wget` mirroring?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough disk space in there ? `df -h .`

Comment: @Slyx: Yes: `99G   49G   45G  52% /home`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be caused by a bug in `wget` that makes it fail on long URLs, or on writing to file names it had derived from long ursl.

See 
[wget starts downloading then stops “cannot write to”](https://serverfault.com/questions/423245/wget-starts-downloading-then-stops-cannot-write-to)

This but looks related, for example:
[bug #21714: File name too long](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21714)

The problem may be solved already in the current version of `wget` - let us know the version you use if it still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm using version 1.14; I will update to newer version and then report in short while. Thanks.